# How do I convert a program made on Notepad to my Arduino on Proteus

Tags: sketch, simulator

I had the Arduino IDE but I accidentally deleted it. I have no internet connection, so I could not download it again. I do not currently possess the Arduino hardware itself but I do have [Proteus](https://www.labcenter.com/) and the Arduino library in it.

So I want to program my Arduino. Previously I would simply write the sketch and compile it and go to where I compiled it and simply add it on my Proteus Arduino and run it. Since I don't have the Arduino IDE, I tried using Notepad and tried to save it as a `.hex` file and run it on Proteus and there was an error created saying `Error reading hex file`.

So how can I program my Arduino on Proteus with the given materials (Notepad, Proteus)? Can it be done? Or is there any other way?

Comment: If you don't have an Internet connection how did you post this question?

Comment: @Transistor This is on my iPhone so I could not download it on my iPhone there is no wifi or LAN cable so simply my internet on my iPhone. What I meant to say was that there is no internet for me to download the Arduino on my PC.

Comment: Create WiFi hotspot on your iPhone and share the internet.

Comment: @BenceKaulics  I tried it and it keeps saying that my connection is limited.

Comment: Download the IDE on your phone, then create a WiFi hotspot on your phone. Connect your PC to your phone wirelessly, then transfer the IDE from your phone to your computer.

Answer (score 3):

Besides displaying source code and letting you edit it, the IDE uses `avr-gcc` (and half a dozen other `avr-` utilities, like `avr-objcopy, avr-ar, avr-nm`) to compile and link the code and convert it to an `elf` or `hex` form, then uses `avrdude` to download it.  Using proteus, you can get by without  `avrdude`, but not without a suitable compiler and linker.

If you have a micro-SD slot on your phone, perhaps you can download the IDE to a card and then move the card to your computer to install the IDE.